# What is the license of the SNAP data sets?

Tags: open-data

The SNAP (Stanford Network Analysis Project) consist of software libraries and network data sets. The software libraries are distributed under the BSD license.

https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/license.html:

> SNAP is distributed under the BSD license. This means that it is free for both academic and commercial use. Note however that some third party components in SNAP require that you reference certain works in scientific publications.

https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/ states this specifically for the source code:

> Complete source code for the core SNAP and GLib libraries is available under the BSD license.

Does this license apply to the network data sets, do they fall under a different license (or multiple different licenses), or is their license unspecified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasets are not part of the code and as such not covered by the source code license; they are also not distributed as a bundle but offered separately.

The data sets don't have a particular license specified (as far as I can establish) - and as such they fall under normal copyright law.

On the data set pages a citation recommendation is given. Many (or all?) offer directly a bibtex entry and a bibliographic source for their origin, thus a way to cite their usage when being used in work which is the basis for scientific, technical or other publications. As such they seem offered for use to anyone - but as no license is given any further distribution (commercially or non-commercially) is prohibited unless explicitly granted (no license = no rights beyond what the general law allows; and that's not much).

Comment: I am not convinced those datasets are actually subject to copyright protection. A collection of basic facts is not protected by copyrights.

Comment: Looking at a few data sets in the process, I'm not convinced that they are mere 'basic facts'. Depending where you live they might also fall under some variation of database right.